# Automatic changes file in Visual Studio for versioning

Tags: c#, visual-studio, versioning

Hy!

So, I'm developing some Class Libraries in C# using VS2013 and I would like to have a file ("Changes.txt") where I put some entries when I'm developing like:

```
new feature that bakes an egg..
new feature that cooks a potato..
```

And when I Release the library it puts on top of the file something like:

```
Version 3.4.4456.12986 released on 15-04-2015
new feature that bakes an egg..
new feature that cooks a potato..
Version 3.3.3221.85776 released on 10-04-2015
support for add new cook items..
```

This way it's easy for me to track what's in each release.

Comment: You can add text-file to the project. Content is a manual job however.

Comment: what is the question? You cought eventually generate the file automatically this file from git repository history, for example by using https://github.com/jeromerg/NGitVersion

Comment: imho, a branchable Trunk under source control give better support for achieve your task